# Find a set such that $A\in B$ and $A\subseteq B$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, examples-counterexamples

> Find a set such that $A\in B$ and $A\subseteq B$.

I was thinking about the $\mathcal P(A)$ to be the answer of this but I'm not sure about $A\subseteq B$.

Comment: Try $A=\emptyset$.

Comment: Try $\{A,\{A\}\}$.

Comment: Could you please post the statement with a proper notation (the title says "$A\subset B$" but in the message it says "$A\subseteq B$"), and explain what is the difference between "Find a set" and "Give an example"?

Comment: @MichaelHoppe What do you mean by $\{A, \{A\}\}$?

Comment: @manooooh no difference, and i will edit it

Comment: @MichaelHoppe and why $\mathcal P (A)$, wouldn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A=\{x\}$ and $B=\{\{x\}, x\}$

Then, $A\in B$ and $A\subseteq B$; since $\forall y\in A$, $y \in B$

$P(A)= \{x| x\subseteq A \}$

Suppose $A=\{x\}$, then $P(A)=B=\{\{x\}, \{\emptyset \}, \{x, \emptyset \}\}$

As you can see, $A\in P(A)$, but $A\not \subseteq P(A)$. Since, $x\notin P(A)$

Comment: So inclusion $\subseteq$ means that the set $A$ is in that set and $\in$ means that all elements of $A$ are in that set, right?

Comment: @C.Cristi $A\subseteq B$ means $\forall x \in A(x\in B)$.

Answer (score 0):

Every ordinal and its successor as defined by Von Neumann satisfy this property.

See [Von Neumann definition of ordinals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number#Von_Neumann_definition_of_ordinals)

Comment: In fact, if you extend the domain of the successor (class) function, every *set* and its successor satisfy this property. :-)